# SQL query to group when value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in my sql db,

```
value                   timestamp
    0 ,   2018-03-21 14:32:24.417
    0 ,   2018-03-21 14:33:24.417
    0 ,   2018-03-21 14:34:24.417
    4 ,   2018-03-21 14:35:24.417
    4 ,   2018-03-21 14:36:24.417
    0 ,   2018-03-21 14:37:24.417
    0 ,   2018-03-21 14:38:24.417
```

I want the results to look as below

```
value,               min timestamp , duration of how long value was in this value
    0 ,    2018-03-21 14:32:24.417,     2
    4 ,    2018-03-21 14:35:24.417,     1
    0 ,    2018-03-21 14:37:24.417,     1
```

I tried using lead function, but since value repeats, it is not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On SQL-Server:

> ```
> select value, min(timestamp), datediff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) diff
> from
>     (select value, [timestamp], 
>              sum(reset) over (order by timestamp) as grp
>      from 
>             (select value, [timestamp],
>                     case when coalesce(lag(value) over (order by timestamp), '19000101') <> value then 1 end as reset
>              from   tbl) t1
>     ) t2
> group by value, grp
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> value | (No column name)    | diff
> ----: | :------------------ | ---:
>     0 | 21/03/2018 14:32:24 |    2
>     4 | 21/03/2018 14:35:24 |    1
>     0 | 21/03/2018 14:37:24 |    1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43f09ab8dbdd1b725d5aa0d3c09e73fe)*

Comment: I'm glad to help.